# SSH make copy of directory?

Tags: centos, ssh

Is it possible to make a copy of a directory via SSH? Lets say I have /directory/ and I want to make an exact copy of it to something like /directory_copy/ is it possible?

I'm using CentOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But this is not a SSH thing. It is just a Linux command `cp -a directory directory_copy`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this remotely using ssh use rsync:

```
rsync -e ssh -aHS SOURCE DESTINATION
```

SOURCE or DESTINATION migth be a remote host.

The only thing that will be not be copied exactly is the time-stamp of a symbolic link.